# How to open RadWindow

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, telerik, c#-3.0

My Code:

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="btnAddReport" runat="server" OnClientClick="return AddFavoritePopup()"
ImageUrl="~/Content/images/add_favorite.jpg" Width="24px" Height="20px" 
style="vertical-align:middle"/>

    function AddFavoritePopup() {
    var radWindow = document.getElementById('AddFavoriteRadWindow');
    radWindow.show()
    }

      <telerik:RadWindowManager runat="server" ID="RadWindowManager2" Title="Add Favorite"
            Behaviors="Close" VisibleStatusbar="False" Modal="False">
            <Windows>
                <telerik:RadWindow ID="AddFavoriteRadWindow" Width="500" Height="300" VisibleOnPageLoad="false" CssClass="radwindow" runat="server">
                    <ContentTemplate>
                        <table>
                            <tr>
                                <asp:Label ID="lblFavorite" runat="server" Text="Favorites: "></asp:Label>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtReportFavorite" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <asp:Button ID="btnOk" runat="server" Text="OK" Width="50" Height="25" onclick="btnOk_Click" />
                                <asp:Button ID="btnCancel" runat="server" Text="Cancel" Width="50" Height="25" onclick="btnCancel_Click" />
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </ContentTemplate>
                </telerik:RadWindow>
            </Windows>
        </telerik:RadWindowManager>
```

How to open RadWindow in the script. I tried with show function. It is not opening. Thanks.

Comment: for your help : http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/window-programming-opening.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
  var oWnd = $find("<%=AddFavoriteRadWindow.ClientID%>");
    oWnd.show();
```

or alternate

```
    var oManager = GetRadWindowManager();       
    oManager.open(null, "AddFavoriteRadWindow");
```

Answer (score 1):

The window does not appear because when the code is executed, not all controls on the page are fully rendered yet.

What you can do to avoid that is to use the **Sys.Application.add_load** function to hook to the 
***ShowWindow*** function to the load event e.g :

```
 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    { 
        string script = "<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>Sys.Application.add_load(ShowWindow);</script>"; 
        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "showWindoww", script);  
    }
```

Click [here](http://www.asp.net/ajax/documentation/live/ClientReference/Sys/ApplicationClass/SysApplicationLoadEvent.aspx) for more details regarding **Sys.Application.add_load**

Thanks.